# AnjularJS Not Preventing Default Form Submit via $compile

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a form being passed to `$('#some-div').append($compile($('#my-form').html())(scope));`
**Angular is not suppressing the default form submit behavior** of refreshing the damn page.

I believe this has something do to with passing the html through the compile function after normal page render. Any idea on how to get AngularJS to prevent refresh on submit?

AngularJS should prevent this form action by default.
[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform)

Also, I know its bad style to manipulate the DOM like this with AngularJS, the actually application is provide HTML content to a Bootstrap popover, this is just a simpler example of the problem.

**-- UPDATE --**

Should have done this to begin with sry.
http://plnkr.co/edit/EbyN2SYG2Gs81knxPvO5?p=preview

Comment: Works flawlessly: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sLxgbaKWtjipzvp7txgE).

Comment: Hmm, looking into this. Not sure what going on???

Comment: Check the update. Just a quick and dirty example. It might have something to due with the popover, because your right; it doesn't happen in your example.

Comment: Maybe an AngularJS bug, should I report it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `form` directive of angular adds an event handler that prevents form submission, if no `action` attribute is defined.

The boostrap popover plugin detaches the popup content (the form in your case) from the DOM. Now when that happens angular removes its event handler to prevent a memory leak. So the form will be submitted.

The solution is to prevent the submission yourself. in HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="insert($event)">
```

Mind the `$event` parameter. And in your code:

```
$scope.insert = function($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
```

It's hard to tell if you can consider that a bug. But the behavior should at least be documented.